# Sending variables from two different HTML sources to a single PHP script using HTML/PHP/JScript only

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I have a situation in which a page is built off two different sources with HTML by combining with each other in a containter third page. Each section also has a variable they pass through a form using POST to a single PHP file. These variables change in every execution (When they form a page together).

For example:

```
<!--Start of HTML 3 -->
<html>
<!-- Start of HTML 1 -->
<body>

<a href='process.php' id='php1' name='php1' onclick='document.getElementById("infoForm").submit()'> A link to php file that receives a hidden form's value</a>

<form id='infoForm' action='process.php' method='POST'>
  <input name ="var1" id="var1" value="changing1" hidden /> 
</form>
<p>Stuff here</p>
<!-- End of HTML 1 -->

<!-- Start of HTML 2 -->
<p>Some more stuff here</p>
<form id='infoForm2' action='process.php' method='POST'>
  <input name ="var2" id="var2" value="changing2" hidden /> 
</form>

</body>
<!-- End of HTML 2 -->
</html> 
<!-- End of HTML 3 -->
```

A few more details:

The forms are independent of each other, joining them would be difficult since they are created using previous processes that work with other variables.

Code can be added inside HTML 1 and 2, but not 3.

This one will only be able to send var1 to process.php (which can invoke it with $_POST). How could I submit both variables to a single PHP file, using a single link, using basic technologies (e.g. Excluding JQuery, AJAX, etc)? Is there a better way than using forms/POST without using the URI?

EDIT: The method I used was @glenn ferns first point: use the form attribute to attach the second one to the first form in the html makeup:

```
<!-- Start of HTML 2 -->
<p>Some more stuff here</p>

<input form="infoForm" name ="var2" id="var2" value="changing2" hidden /> 

</body>
<!-- End of HTML 2 -->
```

Comment: I see that you can submit them already to the same page. Where exactly the problem?

Comment: @Mouneer : Being able to send both variables at the same time while clicking once on the link.

Comment: Ok why don't you just merge the forms into just one form?

Comment: You can't post two forms at once to the same page at the same time. Even if you do this with ajax, you would still get two different requests to the page. You need to make just one request, like combine the two forms into one which you post. Alternatively, you could make a js function that just gets the values from both forms and post them in one request using ajax.

Comment: Put the <form> and </form> tags in page 3.  Or add onSubmit handlers that copy data from the other form to this one.

Comment: I updated the post with a few more details which were unclear (For example, why merging the forms into a single one is not possible)

Comment: As you don't have any control on the markup and you don't want to use JavaScript, I'm afraid your problem could not be solved. Why you can't use JavaScript? Or tell us what forces you with the separated markup like these?

Comment: _"using basic technologies (e.g. Excluding JQuery, AJAX, etc)"_ - If js & ajax isn't basic technologies, I don't know what is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways i can think of doing this

-use the form attribute for the input tag in html2 .
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp

-As long as HTML1 and HTML2 are not used independently then you can just open the form in html1 and close it in html 2
Your IDE will probably throw errors, but it should work

-Using js to get the values and submitting the form from the javascript

Comment: Way 1 here is what I ended up using for its simplicity. Referring to one of the forms through the form tag works for making the second variable be linked to the first form, and simply send the first form. I'll detail the answer on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments, you need to submit the forms and catch the variables together. This is not applicable with two forms as they will submit two different requests. And as HTTP is a stateless protocol, every request will be handled away from the other. You can use sessions to store one value from the first request and use it within the handling of the second request.

Another solution could be using JavaScript to send your variables with an Ajax request. (I don't see any valid use case to not use JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly collate the onformation from both forms and send both using ajax and a FormData objec.

```
function submitforms(){
    var f2=document.getElementById('infoForm2');
    var data=new FormData( document.getElementById('infoForm') );
    for( i=0; i < f2.elements.length; i++ )data.append( f2.elements[i].name, f2.elements[i].value );
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
            alert(this.response)
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST','process.php',true);
    xhr.send( data );
}
```